# regEx positive lookbehind in VBA language

Tags: regex, vba, positive-lookbehind

I want to run regEx positive lookbehind in VBA language, but it is not supported in VBA language. The process I want to run is **(?<=src="")[\w-.]+(?=/)?**

How can I alternatively write **(?<=src="")** here?

Sample: https://regexr.com/65cmi

Comment: No need of lookbehind, you can simply use `src=""([\w.-]+)(?=/)` and get the `match.Submatches(0)` value

Comment: The code I wrote here was a cross section of my regEx expression. If we look at the whole statement, what solution would you suggest?

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ftV89QPwx8/

Comment: `strPattern = "https?\W*|www\.|(src="")[\w.-]+"` and then `regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")`